# How to extract the text between anchor tag in PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, html-parsing, anchor

I've one string in a variable titled `$message` as follows :

```
$message = 'posted an event in <a href="http://52.1.47.143/group/186/">TEST PRA</a>';
```

I only want to get the text within anchor tag i.e. **TEST PRA** in this case using PHP.

How should I do this in an efficient way? Can someone please help me in this regard?

Comment: `preg_match_all('~>\K[^<>]+(?=<)~', $str, $match);` https://regex101.com/r/fT7gQ8/1

Comment: Or some sort of HTML parser in PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` function inorder to do a global match.

```
preg_match_all('~>\K[^<>]*(?=<)~', $str, $match);
```

Here `preg_match` would be enough. `\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final, so it won't consider the previouslly matched `>` character. You could use a positive lookbehind instead of `\K` also , like `(?<=>)`. `[^<>]*` Negated character class, which matches any character but not of `<` or `>`, zero or more times. `(?=<)`, Positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match must be followed by `<` character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fT7gQ8/2)

```
$str = 'posted an event in <a href="http://52.1.47.143/group/186/">TEST PRA</a>';
preg_match('~>\K[^<>]*(?=<)~', $str, $match);
print_r($match[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
TEST PRA
```

Comment: Why use regex when we have perfectly fine strip_tags available? This could do the trick:
`$str = 'posted an event in <a href="http://52.1.47.143/group/186/">TEST PRA</a>';
print_r(strip_tags($str));`

Answer (score 0):

Regex may be slow sometimes. Also, regex approach is maybe not 100% reliable if some unexpected HTML is being passed to it.

So I would rather do it this way:

```
$temp = new DOMDocument;
$temp->loadHTML($message);
$anchors = $temp->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ( $anchors as $anchor ) {
    echo $anchor->textContent;
}
```