# How to get desire innertext from html tag in simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have some text in which there is codes. I want to get last text from the link. here is an example

```
Some text<a href="http://beezfeed.cu.ma">Beezfeed.cu.ma</a><br>
another text<a href="http://google.com">Google.com</a><br>
```

I want to get Google.com text from the above code. I have tried and use Simple html dom. Anyway Here is my code

```
   <?PHP
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
function tags($ddd){
$bbb=$ddd->find('a',1);
    foreach($bbb as $bs){
    echo $bs->innertext;
    }
}
$html = str_get_html('Some text<a href="http://beezfeed.cu.ma">Beezfeed.cu.ma</a><br>
another text<a href="http://google.com">Google.com</a><br>');

echo tags($html);
?>
```

I want to get Google.com how to get. Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048706/how-to-extract-the-text-between-anchor-tag-in-php`

Comment: I have change the code a bit. Take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you use some external library to parse HTML. Any HTML you need. As you need today or in future needs.
Some very good tools are named inside [these stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

I personally use [simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) since ages with very good results.

Comment: `echo $bbb[0]->innerText` will give you the content "Google.com" which seems that you need, just after parsing

Comment: And I will call things as they are, so it will be : `$parser` for the parser handler, and `$htmlContent` to the html content which will be parsed.